# How do you describe something as "family-friendly"?

Tags: word-requests, phrase-requests

Google gives me 家族向け, but it seems like its used to describe things like vehicles, properties and tourist spots that are "for families (with 3-4+ members)", rather than media such as video games and movies that are suited for family members of all ages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

家族向け is not bad, but you can also say 家族で楽しめるゲーム, 家族で楽しめる映画, etc.